# Add word wrap to Android TextView inside Flow widget

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, android-constraintlayout

Is there a way to make `TextView` perform a word wrap in case attached below?
Word "Sauces" and a comma of `TextView` "Sauces, Spices" should stay in the first line if word wrap is possible.

Also, is it possible to put html entity `&bull;` directly into view (`android:text="&bull;"`) and avoid setting it through Java using `setText( Html.fromHtml("&bull;") )`?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/CategoriesConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingStart="0sp"
    android:paddingTop="0sp"
    android:paddingEnd="0sp"
    android:paddingBottom="10sp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:id="@+id/CategoriesFlow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="/* set by Java */"
        app:flow_horizontalAlign="center"
        app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
        app:flow_horizontalGap="0sp"
        app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
        app:flow_verticalAlign="center"
        app:flow_verticalBias="0"
        app:flow_verticalGap="0sp"
        app:flow_verticalStyle="packed"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"/>

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/Subcategory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:letterSpacing="-0.05"
        android:paddingTop="3sp"
        android:paddingBottom="3sp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/lightGrey" />

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/SubcategoryCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:letterSpacing="-0.05"
        android:paddingTop="6sp"
        android:paddingBottom="0sp"
        android:paddingStart="7sp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@color/lighterGrey" />

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/SubcategoryDivider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="15sp"
        android:paddingEnd="15sp"
        android:paddingTop="1sp"
        android:paddingBottom="0sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="35sp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Current state with Flow widget]